# postgresql updating column with NULL from the same column with data

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

Table name: `myTable`, where I need to update the values of A with `Null` from the same column

```
Group      Value
A            10
A            NULL
A            NULL
A            10
B            20
B            20
B            20
C            30
```

Expected:

```
Group      Value
A            10
A            10
A            10
A            10
B            20
B            20
B            20
C            30
```

MY query:

```
Update myTable
Set myTable.Age = b.Age
FROM myTable b
WHERE A.Age is Null
```

I am getting `relation doesn't exist`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest to join these tables in where clause, otherwise it would result in cartesian product.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query

```
UPDATE myTable SET Age = 
    (SELECT b.Age 
     FROM myTable b 
     WHERE b.Group = myTable.Group AND  b.Age IS NOT NULL
     LIMIT 1) 
WHERE Age IS NULL
```

Comment: my only question here is why LIMIT 1

Comment: @user2934524 Because in your table could be several rows for Group = A.
For example table contains these rows (A, 10), (A, 20). So, LIMIT 1 choose only one row with Value=10.

Answer (score 1):

I think a correlated subquery might be the way to go:

```
update myTable t
    set Age = (select t2.Age from mytable t2 where t2.name = t.name and t2.Age is not null)
    where t.Age is Null;
```

Note:  This will generate an error if `age` is on more than one row of the original data for a given `name`.

If performance is an issue, you want an index on `mytable(name, age)`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=ee42eb752d08b3820e3ea4f6b66b6936) is a db<>fiddle example.

Comment: I ran this and its been 10 mins and still running

Comment: IT completed after an hour but didnt update anything

Comment: @user2934524 . . . The code works.  I provided an example.